# Loop through directory and run a command

Tags: bash

I want to run the following command

```
./mc cp --recursive local//first/second remote//first/second
```

I want to loop through `local//first` and find all directories and run `./mc cp` for each directories

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not important , I just want to run a command in a loop can you help me to iterate over directory and run the command multiple time?

Comment: Why don't you just do a `cp --recursive //first remote//first`? The whole point of _recursive_ is that it goes recursively through all intries below the starting directory. No need ot write a loop then.

Comment: my command is not `cp` it is `./mc cp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `local//first` only contains directories, this should work for you:

```
./mc cp -r local//first/* remote//first
```

For a general case you can also use `find` to list all directories:

```
find local//first -type d
```

Then do whatever with this list using `-exec` or pipe it into `xargs`:

```
find local//first -type d -path "local//first/*" -prune -exec ./mc cp --recursive {} remote//first \;
```

Read more in documentation ([find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use find tool to do such thing

```
find . -type d -exec echo {} \;
```

your command would something be like

```
find . -type d -exec ./mc cp --recursive "local/{}" "remote/{}" \;
```